# Definite integral: $\int^\pi_0 e^{2a \cos x} \left( \frac{\sin^2 x}{1- \cos x} \right) dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

The goal is to solve this:
$$
\int^\pi_0 e^{2a \cos x} \left( \frac{\sin^2 x}{1- \cos x} \right) dx
$$
with $a>0$. Really not sure how to attack this one. The integrand seems to be capable of admitting some complex-analysis technique, but not sure how.

Comment: The title has $a$, and the post has $2a$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Really not sure how to attack this one.*

No wonder you're not sure ! :-$)$ It can only be expressed in terms the special [Bessel functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function).

$I=\pi\Big(I_0(2a)+I_1(2a)\Big)$.

Comment: It should be $I=\pi\left(I_{0}\left(2a\right)+I_{1}\left(2a\right)\right)$.

Comment: @MarcoCantarini: The title and the body of the main post differed originally; see comment.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to expand on the @Lucian's answer in case someone is confused:

$$
\int^\pi_0 e^{2a \cos x} \left( \frac{\sin^2 x}{1- \cos x} \right) dx=\int^\pi_0 e^{2a \cos x} \left( \frac{1-\cos^2 x}{1- \cos x} \right) dx=\int^\pi_0 e^{2a \cos x}  (1+\cos x)~ dx=
$$

$$=\int^\pi_0 e^{2a \cos x} ~ dx+\int^\pi_0 e^{2a \cos x}\cos x ~ dx$$

Using the integral definition of modified Bessel function of the first kind of order $n$ with $n$ being whole number:

$$I_n(t)=\frac{1}{\pi} \int^\pi_0 e^{t \cos x}\cos nx ~ dx$$

We recover @Lucian's answer.